# How can I play video file with .vmw extension?

Tags: software-installation, codecs

I tried VLC and mplayer, but both failed to play video file with .vmw extension. I have given the following message

> Required plugin could not be found
>
> Python (v2.7) requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: video/x-asf-unknown decoder

Comment: **Note:** Below answers suggesting to install w32codecs from medibuntu.org will not work anymore. See [Any new way to install w32codecs / w64codecs through apt-get?](http://askubuntu.com/q/359344/40581) regarding this package.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean **.wmv** instead of .vmw?

Answer (score 2):

There is no .VMW video file extension. After a detailed research I found what you meant is .WMV extension. This is simply a video compression format launched by Microsoft just for market competition. To see all the available video encapsulation formats [click here.](https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/video-encapsulation-format-container_8_8_31953612.html)

For the above reason, this type of files is proprietary and Windows didn't allow open source software, such as Ubuntu, to read this codecs until recently. Follow [this link](https://www.wikihow.com/Play-Wmv-Files-in-Ubuntu) to get full information on what these files are and how to open them inside Ubuntu.

The steps comprise of installing VLC, which I understand you have, and unlocking the "Restricted Extras" package from Ubuntu to unlock WMV files.

For the purpose of clarity, see the encapsulation formats we have in VLC in this screenshot.

[image: screenshot].

I hope this clarifies and takes out all your doubts in the Q&A. Success!

Answer (score -1):

You can go [here](http://www.medibuntu.org/repository.php) and add the ppa. Then type in the terminal **sudo apt-get update** once done open the software center and search for **w32 codecs or w64 codecs** which ever your computer needs, also search in the software center for **Ubuntu-Restricted-Extras** install these and I am sure this should fix your issue

Comment: thanks for help ... but when i typed the first command i got an error (ERROR: certificate common name mail.pocentek.net' doesn't match requested host name www.medibuntu.org'. To connect to www.medibuntu.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate')

Comment: Maybe just try installing Ubuntu restricted extras that might work for what ya need. I am not sure why you got an error message, but I am sure the ubuntu restricted extras should work you can find it in the software center

Comment: you can copy and paste the command into a terminal, cause when we type commands in the terminal sometimes we mistype something

Answer (score -1):

Add the medibuntu repository

```
sudo -E wget --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list && sudo apt-get --quiet update && sudo apt-get --yes --quiet --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring && sudo apt-get --quiet update
```

Then install all the needed packages, and then some.

```
sudo apt-get install app-install-data-medibuntu apport-hooks-medibuntu w32codecs ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

You can now play almost any media file.
Note: change the `w32codecs` to `w64codecs` if you have a x64 system architecture PC/laptop!

Comment: thanks for help ... but when i typed the first command i got an error (ERROR: certificate common name `mail.pocentek.net' doesn't match requested host name `www.medibuntu.org'.
To connect to www.medibuntu.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate')

Comment: @azaer try this `sudo apt-get install -f` it might! work.

Comment: Medibuntu no longer exists; this is now obsolete.