# Any new way to install w32codecs / w64codecs through apt-get?

Tags: apt, medibuntu

I'm making a customized ubuntu system.  We used to add medibuntu repository in order to let users install w32codecs / w64codecs.  However medibuntu is closed now.  (http://medibuntu.org).  Would anyone please tell me where I can find a new way to install them through apt-get?

Comment: Would you not be able to get everything you need from the restricted extras package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What is or was w32codecs/w64codecs anyway?

This package is a collection of old and very rarely used codecs. They are very inefficient and deliver poor results for todays standards. The only reason you would want to install them is to convert old private recordings or projects into more compatible formats. You may find everything else in compatible formats online these days.

Contrary to **libdvdcss**, which is now hosted by [videolan.org](http://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html) (see also: [I can't install libdvdcss - script not finding medibuntu, How to get DVD playback?](https://askubuntu.com/q/356046)), you really don't need these codecs in your standard setup, as the unstripped versions of [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/), [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) and [libav](http://libav.org) offer great support for formats that became popular with P2P file sharing and online audio/video publishing.

(For example DivX, XviD, Micosoft MPEG-4, Intel 263 and some Quicktime codecs are all some sort of implementation of [MPEG-4 Part 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_2), the predecessor of MPEG-4 Part 10/AVC/H.264.)

The most detailed explanation I could find was from [deb-multimedia.org](http://www.deb-multimedia.org/dists/unstable/non-free/binary-i386/package/w32codecs)'s package description:

> This package contain video codecs for popular proprietary formats not
>   natively supported by mplayer.
>
> - ATI VCR-2 video codec.
> - Cinepak video codec
> - DivX ;-) video codec, ver. 3.11
> - DivX ;-) video codec, ver. 4.x
> - Indeo Video 3.2/4.1/5.0/4.1 quick/5.0 quick codecs.
> - Intel 263 video codec.
> - Microsoft MPEG-4 video codec, beta version 3.0.0.2700
> - Morgan Multimedia Motion JPEG video codec.
> - QuickTime
> - RealAudio
> - RealVideo 8
> - RealVideo 9
> - Windows Media Video 9

The complete content listing of the package looks like this:

```
$ dpkg --contents w32codecs_20110131-dmo2_i386.deb
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-08-07 11:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-08-07 11:43 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-08-07 11:43 ./usr/lib/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-08-07 11:43 ./usr/lib/codecs/
-rw-r--r-- root/root    184320 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/frwt.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    482816 2010-03-30 13:43 ./usr/lib/codecs/VFCodec.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    319488 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/pvmjpg21.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    331776 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/ZyGoVideo.qtx
-rw-r--r-- root/root     17920 2000-07-30 06:36 ./usr/lib/codecs/msadp32.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root     69632 2010-03-31 16:14 ./usr/lib/codecs/CUVCcodc.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root      3260 2004-07-24 15:41 ./usr/lib/codecs/vid_cyuv.xa
-rw-r--r-- root/root    308736 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/AppleProResDecoder.qtx
-rw-r--r-- root/root     49664 2002-04-21 03:30 ./usr/lib/codecs/nsrt2432.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root     77824 2010-03-30 13:45 ./usr/lib/codecs/fmcodec.DLL
-rw-r--r-- root/root    299008 2002-04-21 03:32 ./usr/lib/codecs/rt32dcmp.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     25088 1999-05-05 23:22 ./usr/lib/codecs/msgsm32.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root    196608 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/pvljpg20.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    102439 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/sipr3260.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    262416 2001-05-11 00:04 ./usr/lib/codecs/mpg4ds32.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root     36864 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/frapsvid.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root   1184984 2006-05-20 17:16 ./usr/lib/codecs/wvc1dmod.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root      9984 2010-06-03 11:00 ./usr/lib/codecs/md5sum
-rw-r--r-- root/root    823296 2010-03-30 13:27 ./usr/lib/codecs/cinevfw.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    119296 2010-03-30 13:44 ./usr/lib/codecs/wavelet.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     81920 2010-03-30 12:55 ./usr/lib/codecs/zmbv.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    176165 2010-03-16 17:30 ./usr/lib/codecs/drv23260.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     65575 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/cook3260.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    110592 2010-03-30 13:25 ./usr/lib/codecs/MVCodec.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    121344 2010-03-30 12:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/SCLS.DLL
-rw-r--r-- root/root    287744 2000-12-29 20:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/divxa32.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root     33040 2002-04-21 11:09 ./usr/lib/codecs/lhacm.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root     98304 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/sp6x_32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     62808 2012-08-07 11:43 ./usr/lib/codecs/atrc.so.6.0
-rw-r--r-- root/root     57344 2004-02-14 21:10 ./usr/lib/codecs/mi-sc4.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root    296448 2010-03-30 13:56 ./usr/lib/codecs/CineWave.qtx
-rw-r--r-- root/root    412160 2001-01-24 10:28 ./usr/lib/codecs/divxc32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    361184 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/3ivxDSVideoDecoder.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root    573440 2004-12-19 17:51 ./usr/lib/codecs/tvqdec.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     84992 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/14_43260.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     81920 2004-03-23 00:57 ./usr/lib/codecs/LCODCCMW2E.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    778240 2010-03-30 13:34 ./usr/lib/codecs/Sif1_vfw.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    338432 2010-03-30 13:08 ./usr/lib/codecs/LCodcCMP.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    316416 2010-03-30 13:53 ./usr/lib/codecs/3ivx Delta 3.5.qtx
-rw-r--r-- root/root    458752 2010-03-30 12:55 ./usr/lib/codecs/GeoCodec.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    626688 2006-05-11 20:21 ./usr/lib/codecs/vp7vfw.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    367616 2010-03-30 13:31 ./usr/lib/codecs/blox.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    278800 2001-05-01 09:46 ./usr/lib/codecs/wmv8ds32.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root    208935 2010-03-16 17:30 ./usr/lib/codecs/drv33260.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    100352 2010-03-31 16:12 ./usr/lib/codecs/AvidQTAVUICodec.qtx
-rw-r--r-- root/root    126464 2004-07-03 00:36 ./usr/lib/codecs/wnvplay1.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    102400 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/VTZ32.DLL
-rw-r--r-- root/root     16144 2002-04-06 00:00 ./usr/lib/codecs/tsd32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    423424 2010-03-31 16:13 ./usr/lib/codecs/wmavds32.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root     95292 2001-02-15 00:00 ./usr/lib/codecs/atrac3.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root     66560 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/tr2032.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    101376 2010-03-31 16:08 ./usr/lib/codecs/Nstsp32.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root    245760 2004-03-23 00:57 ./usr/lib/codecs/LCMW2.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    299560 2012-08-07 11:43 ./usr/lib/codecs/drv3.so.6.0
-rw-r--r-- root/root     29696 2010-03-30 13:51 ./usr/lib/codecs/decvdo.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     98304 2000-12-18 01:32 ./usr/lib/codecs/imc32.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root     57344 2010-03-30 13:40 ./usr/lib/codecs/wtvc.DLL
-rw-r--r-- root/root    110592 2010-03-30 14:15 ./usr/lib/codecs/smcelp32.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root     82432 2003-08-18 18:52 ./usr/lib/codecs/vdowave.drv
-rw-r--r-- root/root    462848 2001-09-22 15:17 ./usr/lib/codecs/vp31vfw.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    258048 2010-03-30 12:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/SN4Codec.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     75264 2010-04-04 04:25 ./usr/lib/codecs/zlib1.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root      9488 2002-04-21 02:55 ./usr/lib/codecs/tssoft32.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root    454656 2005-05-03 16:23 ./usr/lib/codecs/vsshdsd.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    200080 2012-08-07 11:43 ./usr/lib/codecs/drv2.so.6.0
-rw-r--r-- root/root     98304 2001-04-02 05:57 ./usr/lib/codecs/mcmjpg32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     11776 2003-09-09 06:18 ./usr/lib/codecs/ctadp32.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root    263680 2001-10-11 12:34 ./usr/lib/codecs/mcdvd_32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    107760 2004-07-24 15:41 ./usr/lib/codecs/vid_iv32.xa
-rw-r--r-- root/root     19456 2001-03-30 02:16 ./usr/lib/codecs/imaadp32.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root    471040 2010-03-30 13:34 ./usr/lib/codecs/tm2x.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    167696 2001-06-26 17:53 ./usr/lib/codecs/msh261.drv
-rw-r--r-- root/root     34304 1996-12-16 00:00 ./usr/lib/codecs/qpeg32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     93184 2004-07-03 00:36 ./usr/lib/codecs/wnvwinx.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    225280 2002-11-08 20:04 ./usr/lib/codecs/qtmlClient.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    120320 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/lagarith.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    225552 2001-01-29 09:08 ./usr/lib/codecs/qdv.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    372736 2004-04-28 00:40 ./usr/lib/codecs/vp5vfw.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    167936 2003-04-10 00:48 ./usr/lib/codecs/vsswlt.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    130560 2010-03-30 13:33 ./usr/lib/codecs/aoxdxipl.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root     45056 2010-03-30 12:59 ./usr/lib/codecs/msvidc32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     61952 2001-04-10 21:39 ./usr/lib/codecs/acelpdec.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root    360448 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/pvwv220.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     49152 2003-04-10 00:49 ./usr/lib/codecs/vssh264core.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    122961 2010-03-31 16:12 ./usr/lib/codecs/csellc.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    180224 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/frwd.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     76112 2001-12-07 14:27 ./usr/lib/codecs/msscds32.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root    167424 2010-03-30 13:44 ./usr/lib/codecs/wv32vfw.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     71580 2004-07-24 15:41 ./usr/lib/codecs/vid_h261.xa
-rw-r--r-- root/root    175616 2002-04-23 15:51 ./usr/lib/codecs/tm20dec.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root     62976 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/BTVVC32.DRV
-rw-r--r-- root/root    241664 2001-07-03 16:01 ./usr/lib/codecs/ubv263d+.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root    118784 2004-03-24 07:21 ./usr/lib/codecs/aslcodec_dshow.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     54272 2010-03-31 16:09 ./usr/lib/codecs/vdowave.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root    335164 2012-08-07 11:43 ./usr/lib/codecs/drv4.so.6.0
-rw-r--r-- root/root    751104 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/On2_VP3.qtx
-rw-r--r-- root/root    135168 2002-04-21 01:52 ./usr/lib/codecs/clrviddd.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    773368 2004-08-11 01:44 ./usr/lib/codecs/wmsdmod.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    807032 2002-11-20 22:03 ./usr/lib/codecs/wmv9dmod.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    124928 2010-03-30 13:51 ./usr/lib/codecs/vdo32_30.drv
-rw-r--r-- root/root    771584 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/wms10dmod.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    155648 2005-04-10 18:06 ./usr/lib/codecs/vmnc.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    199168 2000-07-14 05:52 ./usr/lib/codecs/ir32_32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    410216 2002-10-28 15:11 ./usr/lib/codecs/wmadmod.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    487424 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/smv2vfw.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    124370 2004-07-24 15:41 ./usr/lib/codecs/vid_h263.xa
-rw-r--r-- root/root    212992 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/WavLor.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    218624 1999-04-15 20:10 ./usr/lib/codecs/mvoiced.vwp
-rw-r--r-- root/root      8704 2010-03-30 13:40 ./usr/lib/codecs/KGV1-VFW.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     60772 2012-08-07 11:43 ./usr/lib/codecs/sipr.so.6.0
-rw-r--r-- root/root     33280 2000-08-24 02:00 ./usr/lib/codecs/huffyuv.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     35840 1999-09-09 19:12 ./usr/lib/codecs/asusasvd.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     53248 2010-04-04 04:25 ./usr/lib/codecs/MyFlashZip0.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root    239616 2000-12-21 22:34 ./usr/lib/codecs/divx_c32.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root    192512 2010-03-31 16:11 ./usr/lib/codecs/rricm.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     28672 2003-10-29 16:40 ./usr/lib/codecs/ultimo.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     61440 2010-03-30 12:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/WCMV.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     80896 2010-03-30 13:45 ./usr/lib/codecs/TRICDC32.DRV
-rw-r--r-- root/root    563200 2003-05-27 12:42 ./usr/lib/codecs/QuickTimeEssentials.qtx
-rw-r--r-- root/root   1449984 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/psiv.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     49152 2010-03-30 12:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/ylc.vcm
-rw-r--r-- root/root    184320 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/frwu.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    199680 2004-06-02 18:37 ./usr/lib/codecs/iac25_32.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root    122880 2010-03-30 13:25 ./usr/lib/codecs/nsvideo.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     61440 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/DVACM.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root    671815 2010-03-31 16:14 ./usr/lib/codecs/cseHQa.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    739328 1997-07-07 11:32 ./usr/lib/codecs/ir41_32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     35840 2010-03-31 16:10 ./usr/lib/codecs/xanlib.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    262416 2001-04-02 05:30 ./usr/lib/codecs/wmvds32.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root    217127 2010-03-16 17:30 ./usr/lib/codecs/drv43260.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     77824 2004-03-24 07:21 ./usr/lib/codecs/aslcodec_vfw.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     90112 2002-11-30 23:55 ./usr/lib/codecs/jp2avi.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    110592 2002-04-21 14:38 ./usr/lib/codecs/tsccvid.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    155648 2010-03-30 12:57 ./usr/lib/codecs/BMDCodecLib.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     45056 2010-03-30 13:40 ./usr/lib/codecs/scrvid.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root      6640 2004-07-24 15:41 ./usr/lib/codecs/vid_cvid.xa
-rw-r--r-- root/root    114688 2001-05-03 15:30 ./usr/lib/codecs/avizlib.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    767488 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/ACTLComponent.qtx
-rw-r--r-- root/root    188416 2010-03-30 12:57 ./usr/lib/codecs/libguide40.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    904704 2003-05-27 12:42 ./usr/lib/codecs/QuickTimeInternetExtras.qtx
-rw-r--r-- root/root     56320 2002-12-21 00:44 ./usr/lib/codecs/mwsc.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     58880 2010-03-31 16:08 ./usr/lib/codecs/Nsgsm32.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root    319480 2004-07-24 15:41 ./usr/lib/codecs/vid_3ivX.xa
-rw-r--r-- root/root   4544512 2003-05-27 12:42 ./usr/lib/codecs/QuickTime.qts
-rw-r--r-- root/root     34064 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/lhacm2.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root     76800 2010-03-30 12:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/nuvision.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root     76800 2001-04-18 11:54 ./usr/lib/codecs/BeHereiVideo.qtx
-rw-r--r-- root/root     69632 2001-05-03 15:30 ./usr/lib/codecs/avimszh.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     44032 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/28_83260.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     38912 2002-01-07 00:00 ./usr/lib/codecs/alf2cd.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root    966656 2010-03-30 13:06 ./usr/lib/codecs/GXAMP4.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     76800 1996-11-12 10:12 ./usr/lib/codecs/VDODEC32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    391680 2000-08-01 22:41 ./usr/lib/codecs/i263_32.drv
-rw-r--r-- root/root    110592 2006-09-27 20:56 ./usr/lib/codecs/vcmimm4.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    262144 2010-03-31 16:12 ./usr/lib/codecs/cllccodc.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     65536 2010-03-30 13:40 ./usr/lib/codecs/sp4x_32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     74548 2012-08-07 11:43 ./usr/lib/codecs/cook.so.6.0
-rw-r--r-- root/root     76800 2002-03-12 14:22 ./usr/lib/codecs/vgpix32d.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    114176 2010-03-30 13:40 ./usr/lib/codecs/bw10.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     90112 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/MV3.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     73766 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/atrc3260.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    438272 2004-02-12 09:39 ./usr/lib/codecs/vp6vfw.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    204800 2004-11-14 22:02 ./usr/lib/codecs/lsvxdec.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     53760 2001-05-10 03:51 ./usr/lib/codecs/m3jpegdec.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root    706696 2003-04-10 00:48 ./usr/lib/codecs/vsslight.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    755200 2000-03-09 20:17 ./usr/lib/codecs/ir50_32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    182784 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/ZyGoAudioS.qtx
-rw-r--r-- root/root    110592 2000-03-09 20:15 ./usr/lib/codecs/iccvid.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     88064 2001-01-22 01:49 ./usr/lib/codecs/asusasv2.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    151808 2010-03-17 13:51 ./usr/lib/codecs/scdec.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    131072 2002-09-09 20:01 ./usr/lib/codecs/sp5x_32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    424960 1999-04-15 20:10 ./usr/lib/codecs/msms001.vwp
-rw-r--r-- root/root   4921136 2010-03-30 13:06 ./usr/lib/codecs/G2M.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    466944 2004-04-28 00:39 ./usr/lib/codecs/vp4vfw.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    327680 2010-03-30 13:29 ./usr/lib/codecs/WavCWAIP.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     66560 2010-03-30 12:56 ./usr/lib/codecs/kdvyuv8.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    807528 2002-10-28 15:12 ./usr/lib/codecs/wmvdmod.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    155648 2010-03-30 13:08 ./usr/lib/codecs/AvidAVICodec.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    422912 2002-11-12 09:53 ./usr/lib/codecs/m3jp2k32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    835665 2010-03-31 16:14 ./usr/lib/codecs/CSEUvec.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    312832 2002-04-21 01:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/CLRVIDDC.DLL
-rw-r--r-- root/root     81920 2002-04-21 11:22 ./usr/lib/codecs/CtWbJpg.DLL
-rw-r--r-- root/root    188832 2004-07-24 15:41 ./usr/lib/codecs/vid_iv41.xa
-rw-r--r-- root/root    421888 2003-04-10 00:49 ./usr/lib/codecs/vssh264dec.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    264704 2001-09-03 13:08 ./usr/lib/codecs/m3jpeg32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    614477 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/vorbis.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root     98304 2003-04-10 00:49 ./usr/lib/codecs/vssh264.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    409720 2002-10-29 17:03 ./usr/lib/codecs/wma9dmod.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    254272 1999-06-26 15:31 ./usr/lib/codecs/mpg4c32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    217088 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/slif.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    706504 2010-07-14 23:41 ./usr/lib/codecs/Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.EEScreen.Codec.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    468496 2010-03-30 13:09 ./usr/lib/codecs/ACDV.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     88464 1996-08-14 12:41 ./usr/lib/codecs/DECVW_32.DLL
-rw-r--r-- root/root    352256 2010-03-30 13:34 ./usr/lib/codecs/Sif1Dec.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root     53760 2010-03-30 12:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/Zlib.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     75200 2010-03-31 16:11 ./usr/lib/codecs/ativcr1.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    278528 2010-04-07 13:19 ./usr/lib/codecs/pncrt.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    225280 2001-11-04 00:40 ./usr/lib/codecs/ivvideo.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root   3037696 2010-11-27 14:40 ./usr/lib/codecs/AvidAVdnCodec.qtx
-rw-r--r-- root/root     13239 2003-12-03 22:29 ./usr/lib/codecs/scg726.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root    520192 2001-08-28 22:26 ./usr/lib/codecs/divx.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    117760 2010-03-30 13:44 ./usr/lib/codecs/ADV601.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    486504 2004-04-28 00:43 ./usr/lib/codecs/wmspdmod.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     42320 2010-03-30 13:41 ./usr/lib/codecs/xfcodec.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    770384 2010-03-18 17:15 ./usr/lib/codecs/msvcr100.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    286720 2010-03-30 13:33 ./usr/lib/codecs/camfc.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     88008 2004-07-24 15:41 ./usr/lib/codecs/vid_iv50.xa
-rw-r--r-- root/root   1118208 2008-10-11 11:43 ./usr/lib/codecs/Amv2Codec.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     79872 2001-10-11 15:10 ./usr/lib/codecs/msnaudio.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root     51224 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/sirenacm.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    300544 2000-12-21 22:40 ./usr/lib/codecs/l3codeca.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root     45056 2001-11-16 20:10 ./usr/lib/codecs/pclepim1.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    211968 2003-03-28 16:03 ./usr/lib/codecs/ViVD2.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    150016 2000-08-02 07:28 ./usr/lib/codecs/ativcr2.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    118784 2002-04-21 17:35 ./usr/lib/codecs/ubvmp4d.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     56320 1999-04-15 16:10 ./usr/lib/codecs/voxmsdec.ax
-rw-r--r-- root/root    249856 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/NuB2.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    307200 2001-05-03 15:29 ./usr/lib/codecs/icmw_32.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root   1155808 2010-03-31 15:58 ./usr/lib/codecs/3ivx.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root    122880 2001-05-03 15:34 ./usr/lib/codecs/vivog723.acm
-rw-r--r-- root/root   1181944 2004-10-18 09:33 ./usr/lib/codecs/wmvadvd.dll
-rw-r--r-- root/root     57344 2010-03-30 13:25 ./usr/lib/codecs/MLZCodec.dll
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-08-07 11:43 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-08-07 11:43 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2012-08-07 11:43 ./usr/share/doc/w32codecs/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       627 2012-05-27 09:24 ./usr/share/doc/w32codecs/copyright
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1558 2012-08-07 11:42 ./usr/share/doc/w32codecs/changelog.Debian.gz
```

## Solution

---

**WARNING:** Please read the cited text completely. Don't just copy and paste to terminal!

---

mc4man posted the following on the [forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2175755&s=ea348c3655fe7e32fcae929ac11a499b&p=12794748#post12794748):

> they come from [mplayerhq.hu](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/MPlayer/releases/codecs/) so if one wanted to install as a .deb then
>   they are always here -
>   http://www.deb-multimedia.org/dists/unstable/non-free/binary-i386/package/w32codecs
>
> Or for a couple of extra or if on 64 bit the 3 rarely needed then run
>   this in a terminal (copy & paste as 1 complete command (slightly
>   modded from Andrew.46's mplayer guide
>
> Code:
>
> ```bash
> sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/codecs && \
> if [ "$(uname -m)" = "x86_64" ]; then
>     wget http://www.mplayerhq.hu/MPlayer/releases/codecs/essential-amd64-20071007.tar.bz2
>     tar xjvf essential-amd64-20071007.tar.bz2
>     sudo cp -v essential-amd64-20071007/* /usr/lib/codecs
> else
>     wget http://www.mplayerhq.hu/MPlayer/releases/codecs/all-20110131.tar.bz2
>     tar xjvf all-20110131.tar.bz2
>     sudo cp -v all-20110131/* /usr/lib/codecs
> fi
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The package you are looking for is `ubuntu-restricted-extras` which installs pretty much everything you needed from medibuntu repositories:

```
apt-cache depends ubuntu-restricted-extras
ubuntu-restricted-extras
  Depends: ubuntu-restricted-addons
  Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer
  Recommends: unrar
  Recommends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse
  Recommends: libavcodec-extra-53
```

The gstreamer plugins bad multiverse has several of the restricted codecs:

```
apt-cache show gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse
Package: gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse
Priority: optional
Section: multiverse/libs
Installed-Size: 249
Maintainer: Sebastian Dröge , Onkar Shinde 
Architecture: amd64
Source: gst-plugins-bad-multiverse0.10
Version: 0.10.21-1ubuntu1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libfaac0, libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8), libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 (>= 0.10.32), libgstreamer0.10-0 (>= 0.10.32), libmjpegutils-2.0-0, libmpeg2encpp-2.0-0, libmplex2-2.0-0, libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1), libxvidcore4 (>= 1.2.2)
Filename: pool/multiverse/g/gst-plugins-bad-multiverse0.10/gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse_0.10.21-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Size: 82916
MD5sum: ae024a5e17ada89e173baa3f59cc35f3
SHA1: ae66c21ed3f28d44c433cf7921fdd7f7e2a94e50
SHA256: bf50862ad277efe3631f61f00286d8ff3d52db1a8582bd81b772ad659bfc98f4
Description-en: GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set (Multiverse Variant)
 GStreamer is a streaming media framework, based on graphs of filters
 which operate on media data.  Applications using this library can do
 anything from real-time sound processing to playing videos, and just
 about anything else media-related.  Its plugin-based architecture means
 that new data types or processing capabilities can be added simply by
 installing new plug-ins.
 .
 GStreamer Bad Plug-ins is a set of plug-ins that aren't up to par compared
 to the rest. They might be close to being good quality, but they're missing
 something - be it a good code review, some documentation, a set of tests, a
 real live maintainer, or some actual wide use.
Gstreamer-Elements: faac, mpeg2enc, mplex, xviddec, xvidenc
Gstreamer-Encoders: audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int){ 4, 2 }, stream-format=(string){ adts, raw }; video/mpeg, systemstream=(boolean)false, mpegversion=(int){ 1, 2, 4 }; video/mpeg, systemstream=(boolean)true; video/x-xvid
```

Just download and install these packages and you will be all good.